Couldn't a validator maliciously update a program before my transaction executes to hijack accounts?
Say I send a transaction that interacts with a program and the wallet simulation appears benign, but the program owner colludes with the validator.
Is there anything to stop the validator handling my transaction from updating the program to hijack all accounts, ordering my transaction to execute after the program update is fully executed within the same slot?

What wallet do you interact with ?

It's absolutely possible, which is why you shouldn't trust transaction simulation too much.
